# SQL query to update gaps in dataset in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following problem with my SQL update, or better said: I do not know how to do it.

I have to update a dataset on DB2.
So does my dataset look like.

```
NUM_CUS      COD_ENTITY      BRN_OPEN        COD_PRODSERV   NUM_ACCOUNT   KEY_ENTITY  KEY_PARTIC PARTSEQ 
11111111           0100       0010              98              60607998     0100         T         01   
20000264           0100       0010              98              60607998     0100         Y         02
```

Now the row: NUM_CUS = '20000264' has to be updated, especially the field PARTSEQ.
It has to be updated to PARTSEQ = '01'.

The row with NUM_CUS: '11111111' and KEY_PARTIC = 'T' is the 'primary row'!
But it could also be that we have 3 rows where there is a gap in PARTSEQ, like here

```
NUM_CUS      COD_ENTITY      BRN_OPEN        COD_PRODSERV   NUM_ACCOUNT   KEY_ENTITY  KEY_PARTIC PARTSEQ 
11111111           0100       0010              98              60607998     0100         T         01   
22222222           0100       0010              98              60607998     0100         Y         03   
20000264           0100       0010              98              60607998     0100         Y         04
```

Then PARTSEQ: 03 should be updated to 01, and PARTSEQ: 04 must be updated to 02.

Can somebody tell me how it is possible to updated the field to the appropriate numbers.

Comment: You must describe the formal rule of such an update. Not just "I want to update this values to that value". For example, why should you have the following updates: `03->01 and 04->02`? Why not `03->02 and 04->01`? Why is the row with `NUM_CUS='11111111'  and KEY_PARTIC = 'T'` not updated? Is this because it's some "untouchable" row, and all such rows must not be updated?

Comment: I understand your point. The reason why is that `NUM_CUS='11111111'  and KEY_PARTIC = 'T'` define a main owner, whereas `KEY_PARTIC='Y' and PARTSEQ='03'` are members.

Answer (score 0):

if only the first row has KEY_PARTIC  = 'T', you can use ROW_NUMBER function like that :

```html
create table temp as
 select NUM_CUS,PARTSEQ ,ROW_NUMBER ( )   
    OVER (   PARTITION BY NUM_CUS ORDER BY PARTSEQ  asc) as rank
 From <Table_name> 
WHERE KEY_PARTIC ='Y';
```

Then Update PARTSEQ  in your table by rank value of Temp table.

Comment: Thanks, for the hint with the row_number.
Unfortunately, the create table statement is not working with this DB2 version.
Could be an older one.

Comment: if u can't create new table, try to update using the select query, i hope that this post can help you. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205054/update-using-select-in-db2#

Comment: Thanks, I will see how I can use your SQL statement and try to close the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE
(
SELECT PARTSEQ, LPAD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PARTSEQ), 2, '0') PARTSEQ_NEW  
FROM MYTAB
WHERE KEY_PARTIC <> 'T'
)
SET PARTSEQ = PARTSEQ_NEW  
WHERE PARTSEQ <> PARTSEQ_NEW;
```